# Need help getting the input to loop after a failed validation in Python

Tags: python, loops, validation

I'm making a program for school, and in one part I'm unable to get the input to loop back so that the user can edit their answer, and it just skips ahead to the next input after displaying the error message. I've tried every fix I can think of, but nothing seems to be working.

Here's the code and how it runs:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `continue` to go back to the start of the loop:

```py
while True:
  InvDateStr = input("sfsdofjsadofj")

  if InvDateStr == "": # this error should be first
    print("can't be blank")
    continue

  try:
    InvDate = # baifaisjfoa
  except:
    print("that error")
    continue

  break

# rest of code
```

Comment: I couldn't get a fix using this exact code format, but it did lead me to a fix (I'll add it to the answers if you're curious at all) so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```py
while True:
    InvDateStr = input("Enter the invoice date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")

    if InvDateStr == "":
        print("Invoice date cannot be blank. Please re-enter.")


    try:
        InvDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(InvDateStr, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except:
        print("Date must be in YYYY-MM-DD format. Please re-enter.")
        continue

    break
```